# Angular mat-checkbox performance issue

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, checkbox, angular-material

I have a `mat-list` with a `mat-checkbox` next to each list item. The list is about 700-800 element long.
Whenever I click the `checkbox` there's a huge delay between the check-mark appearing and clicking it.
Any ideas what might cause it? I read it that Angular iterates through every element even if only one is getting changed due to change detection, but even if that's the case, I don't know how to avoid this problem.

```html
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let listItem of productList">    
        <span (click)="selectProduct(listItem)">
            <div matLine>{{listItem.name}}</div>
            <div matLine>{{listItem.desc}}</div>
        </span>
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin check-box" name="listItem.name" [(ngModel)]="listItem.checked"></mat-checkbox>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

**UPDATE**

Using `ChangeDetectorRef` and `.detectChanges()` whenever a click event is called, fixed it.

Comment: You can provide a demo where I/we can check it!

Comment: stackblitz demo would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure, with 700+ data elements..

Comment: @Greg.OHajdu You mentioned you found a solution. Could you post (and accept) an answer with that particular solution?

Comment: See solution right under question, under UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

I have generated some code for you with 700  mat-checkboxes. It takes less than half a second to click with Chrome 73.0.3683.86. Yes, it could be faster, but angular material was never about performance, it was about UI.

Example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-lez2zj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Thank you for spending time on my question. Luckily I've found a solution.

Comment: @Greg.OHajdu which is?

Comment: This example is very slow. The solution is to use simple <input type="checkbox"> and format it with css.

Comment: I have tried to do the same with input, but for me performance was exactly the same:
`<span *ngFor="let food of foods; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" [value]="food.value" [id]="'chb' + i" />
  <label [for]="'chb' + i">{{ food.viewValue }}</label>
</span>`